# What could Cause SegFaults after Successful native calls through JNI?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, sgx

**Context**
I am working on my Master Thesis using Intel SGX in order to use Enclave Code alongside a Java project.

The project uses Gradle for installation, and I have added a .jar containing a Class containing Native calls and the .so file containing the code for these calls.

I am currently only being able to open up an enclave and calculate an EC Curve for DH Key exchange, however, as the java code moves on, segfaults occur. These Segfaults however, dont occur inside the C code, as I am able to retrieve the correct and expected results from the native code in my java project. These segmentation faults usually happen there is heavy I/O workload (At least that is what I deduced so far), usually Sockets, which is something I use, since my thesis is in Distributed Systems.

**C Code:**

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_sgxUtils_SgxFunctions_jni_1initialize_1enclave
  (JNIEnv *env , jobject,jint enclaveId, jbyteArray file_path){

    if(file_path == NULL){
      printf("NULL FILEPATH. error.");
      return -1;
    }
    char token_path[MAX_PATH] = {'\0'};
    sgx_launch_token_t token = {0};
    sgx_status_t ret = SGX_ERROR_UNEXPECTED;
    int updated = 0;
    //Get the id of a given Enclave:
    global_eid = (int)enclaveId;
    int length = snprintf(NULL , 0, "%d", enclaveId) + 1; //Gives the length of the Integer as a String.
    char* id_ptr = (char*)malloc(length); 
    snprintf(id_ptr,length,"%d",enclaveId); 


    /* Step 1: try to retrieve the launch token saved by last transaction 
     *         if there is no token, then create a new one.
     */
    /* try to get the token saved in $HOME */
    const char *home_dir = getpwuid(getuid())->pw_dir;
    
    if (home_dir != NULL && 
        (strlen(home_dir)+strlen("/")+sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME)+1) <= MAX_PATH) {
        /* compose the token path */
        strncpy(token_path, home_dir, strlen(home_dir));
        strncat(token_path, "/", strlen("/"));
        char* correctName = (char*) malloc(length + sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME) + 1);
        memcpy(correctName,id_ptr,length);
        strncat(correctName,TOKEN_FILENAME,sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME)+1);
        strncat(token_path,correctName,length + sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME)+1);
        // strncat(token_path, TOKEN_FILENAME, sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME)+1);
        // free(correctName);
    } else {
        /* if token path is too long or $HOME is NULL */
        strncpy(token_path, TOKEN_FILENAME, sizeof(TOKEN_FILENAME));
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(token_path, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL && (fp = fopen(token_path, "wb")) == NULL) {
        printf("Warning: Failed to create/open the launch token file \"%s\".\n", token_path);
    }


    if (fp != NULL) {
        /* read the token from saved file */
        size_t read_num = fread(token, 1, sizeof(sgx_launch_token_t), fp);
        if (read_num != 0 && read_num != sizeof(sgx_launch_token_t)) {
            /* if token is invalid, clear the buffer */
            memset(&token, 0x0, sizeof(sgx_launch_token_t));
            printf("Warning: Invalid launch token read from \"%s\".\n", token_path);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    /* Step 2: call sgx_create_enclave to initialize an enclave instance */
    /* Debug Support: set 2nd parameter to 1 */

    //Here we obtain the char* of the given Enclave file path:
    size_t filename_size = env->GetArrayLength(file_path);
    jbyte* jb_filePath = env->GetByteArrayElements(file_path,NULL);
   
    char* enclave_filePath = (char*) malloc(filename_size);
    memcpy(enclave_filePath,jb_filePath,filename_size);

    ret = sgx_create_enclave(enclave_filePath, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &global_eid, NULL);
    if (ret != SGX_SUCCESS) {
        if (fp != NULL) fclose(fp);
        return -1;
    }

    /* Step 3: save the launch token if it is updated */
    if (updated == FALSE || fp == NULL) {
        /* if the token is not updated, or file handler is invalid, do not perform saving */
        if (fp != NULL) fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    /* reopen the file with write capablity */
    fp = freopen(token_path, "wb", fp);
    if (fp == NULL) return 0;
    size_t write_num = fwrite(token, 1, sizeof(sgx_launch_token_t), fp);
    if (write_num != sizeof(sgx_launch_token_t))
        printf("Warning: Failed to save launch token to \"%s\".\n", token_path);
    fclose(fp);

    free(id_ptr);
    // env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(file_path,enclave_filePath);
    return 0;
  }

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_sgxUtils_SgxFunctions_jni_1sgx_1begin_1ec_1dh(JNIEnv *env, jobject){
    printf("Begin DH \n");

    if(init_happened == 1){ //Verify if the Random generators were seeded.
      sgx_status_t init_status;
      init_mbed(global_eid,&init_status);
      init_happened = 0;
      //printf("Init happened inside enclave.");
    }

    unsigned char* public_ec_key = (unsigned char*)malloc(EC_KEY_SIZE); //32 bytes allocated. (256)
    printf("Calculating EC_DH.\n");

    //Start the ECDH Ecall.
    sgx_status_t ecdh_status;
    create_ec_key_pair(global_eid,&ecdh_status,public_ec_key,EC_KEY_SIZE); //Send the buffer and its size.
    if(ecdh_status != SGX_SUCCESS){
      printf("Failed. ec_key_pair returned %d\n",ecdh_status);
    }

    //Copy the information to a Jbyte in order to return in a JbyteArray:
    jbyte* toCopy = (jbyte*)malloc(EC_KEY_SIZE * sizeof(jbyte));
    memcpy(toCopy,public_ec_key,EC_KEY_SIZE);

    //Return the Public Key:
    jbyteArray result = env->NewByteArray(EC_KEY_SIZE);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(result,0,EC_KEY_SIZE,toCopy);
    //Free the pointers and return the arrray.
    free(public_ec_key);
    free(toCopy);

    printf("EC_DH Calculated.\n");

    return result;
  }
```

I will omit the large output from Valgrind, it is just a huge file with '?' every line, since SGX hides the Stack trace, giving me no info on the invalid reads/Writes.

**Valgrind Output**

```
==38490== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x6a937a0 --> 0x28789d48
==38490==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=567240104 or greater
==38490== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x28789d48 --> 0x6a937a0
==38490==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=567240104 or greater
==38490== Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x6a97220 --> 0x28789d48
==38490==          to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=567225128 or greater
==38490==          further instances of this message will not be shown.
==38490== 
==38490== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==38490==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x2
==38490==    at 0x27CD0B05: sig_handler_sim(int, siginfo_t*, void*) (in /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_urts_sim.so)
==38490==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==38490==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==38490==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==38490==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==38490==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==38490== 
==38490== HEAP SUMMARY:
==38490==     in use at exit: 16,636,139 bytes in 39,334 blocks
==38490==   total heap usage: 55,264 allocs, 15,930 frees, 71,819,001 bytes allocated
```

**Java Code**

```
    private void initEnclave() {
        this.logger.info("Starting InitEnclave");
        enclave = new SgxFunctions(this.enclaveId);
        try {
            File pemFile = new File(HOME_DIR + "/" + this.enclaveId + ".pem");
            if(!pemFile.exists()) {
                pemFile = SgxFunctions.createPem(this.enclaveId);
            }
            File enclaveFile = new File(HOME_DIR + "/" + this.enclaveId + "enclave_signed.so");
            if(!enclaveFile.exists()) {
                enclave.createSignedEnclave(HOME_DIR, pemFile.getAbsolutePath(), enclaveId);
                this.logger.info("Enclave signed");
            }
            else
                this.logger.info("Enclave file exists. Starting enclave.");
            
            logger.info("ABSOLUTE PATH: " + enclaveFile.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] enclaveFilePath = enclaveFile.getAbsolutePath().substring(0).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            byte[] correctPath = Arrays.copyOf(enclaveFilePath, enclaveFilePath.length+1);
            correctPath[correctPath.length-1] = '\0';
            int created = enclave.jni_initialize_enclave(enclaveId,correctPath);
            if(created == 0)
                this.logger.info("Enclave created.");
            else
                this.logger.info("Enclave failed to create.");
//
//          //Create DH parameters:
            this.dh_params = this.enclave.jni_sgx_begin_ec_dh(); //Begin the Enclave EC parameters for DH key exchange.
            this.logger.info("EC-DH Parameters created for Key exchange.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

If I comment out the 'begin_ec_dh()' Call, the program will not segfault. However, even when running this native call, the Enclave will return an acceptable result and I am able to use the result in my Java code no problem, but only up until a certain point where it segfaults for an unkown reason.

I suspect its obviously my code, but I have no idea what is going on.
Any help is appreciated, Thank you for your help and sorry for the long post.

Edit:

I have added a printf() in order to retrieve a Crash file from the JVM over the filename Pointer.
What I dont understand is that If you look at my C code, I have allocated exactly the Array Size that comes from java (And I have added the null terminator in my Java Code, which was previously the source of another segfault), any idea what is causing this? Seems like I am dereferencing an Invalid pointer, but why is it invalid?

**JVM Crash File**

```
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f9f51fd9627, pid=9910, tid=9911
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (17.0.3+7) (build 17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (17.0.3+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, mixed mode, sharing, tiered, compressed oops, compressed class ptrs, g1 gc, linux-amd64)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libc.so.6+0x188627]
#
# Core dump will be written. Default location: Core dumps may be processed with "/usr/share/apport/apport -p%p -s%s -c%c -d%d -P%P -u%u -g%g -- %E" (or dumping to /home/andrecruz/Tese/Con-BFT/build/install/library/core.9910)
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   Unknown
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -Djava.security.properties=./config/java.security -Djava.library.path=./lib/ -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:ErrorFile=/home/andrecruz/Tese/Con-BFT/ -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dlogback.configurationFile=./config/logback.xml bftsmart.demo.map.MapServer 0 10

Host: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6440HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz, 4 cores, 7G, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Time: Sun May 29 23:13:08 2022 WEST elapsed time: 2.134101 seconds (0d 0h 0m 2s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f9f4c012b40):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9911, stack(0x00007f9f5061b000,0x00007f9f5071c000)]

Stack: [0x00007f9f5061b000,0x00007f9f5071c000],  sp=0x00007f9f50718c28,  free space=1015k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x188627]
C  [libc.so.6+0x61d6f]  _IO_printf+0xaf
j  sgxUtils.SgxFunctions.jni_initialize_enclave(I[B)I+0
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.initEnclave()V+248
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Executable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Recoverable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/RequestVerifier;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Replier;Lbftsmart/tom/util/KeyLoader;I)V+147
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.<init>(ILbftsmart/tom/server/Executable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Recoverable;I)V+17
j  bftsmart.demo.map.MapServer.<init>(II)V+35
j  bftsmart.demo.map.MapServer.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+34
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [libjvm.so+0x83ae75]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8cf4e9]
V  [libjvm.so+0x8d2392]
C  [libjli.so+0x4abe]
C  [libjli.so+0x84ed]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sgxUtils.SgxFunctions.jni_initialize_enclave(I[B)I+0
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.initEnclave()V+248
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.<init>(ILjava/lang/String;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Executable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Recoverable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/RequestVerifier;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Replier;Lbftsmart/tom/util/KeyLoader;I)V+147
j  bftsmart.tom.ServiceReplica.<init>(ILbftsmart/tom/server/Executable;Lbftsmart/tom/server/Recoverable;I)V+17
j  bftsmart.demo.map.MapServer.<init>(II)V+35
j  bftsmart.demo.map.MapServer.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+34
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000020

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000010 is an unknown value
RBX=0x00007f9f51ec7b43: <offset 0x0000000000076b43> in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f9f51e51000
RCX=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000000002f is an unknown value
RSP=0x00007f9f50718c28 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9f4c012b40
RBP=0x00007f9f507191a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9f4c012b40
RSI=0x00007f9f50719168 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9f4c012b40
RDI=0x0000000000000020 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00000000ffffffff points into unknown readable memory: 00
R9 =0x0000000000000009 is an unknown value
R10=0x00007f9f50610099: <offset 0x0000000000007099> in /home/andrecruz/Tese/Con-BFT/build/install/library/lib/libSgx.so at 0x00007f9f50609000
R11=0x000000000000002f is an unknown value
R12=0x00007f9f5203e6a0: _IO_2_1_stdout_+0x0000000000000000 in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 at 0x00007f9f51e51000
R13=0x00007f9f5061008f: <offset 0x000000000000708f> in /home/andrecruz/Tese/Con-BFT/build/install/library/lib/libSgx.so at 0x00007f9f50609000
R14=0x00007f9f507191b0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007f9f4c012b40
R15=0x0000000000000073 is an unknown value
```

Comment: Don't you get an hs_err file/JVM crash log? It seems like maybe the native code, or something else, is installing it's own signal handler, which interferes with JVM features such as implicit null checking. You might try running with `-XX:-ImplicitNullChecks`. But, in general, signal handlers can interfere with the normal functioning of the JVM.

Comment: Also, you could try running with `-Xcheck:jni`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, -Xcheck allows me to run my program no problems, it does warn that it is receiving SIGSEGV signals, It does seem like I am dereferencing an invalid pointer somewhere, the line in question seems to be   
`ret = sgx_create_enclave(enclave_filePath, SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &global_eid, NULL);` , Sorry to bother , I dont really understand why the received pointers are invalid, considering that I can access the values inside them. If you would have any insight, it would be very appreciated

Comment: You created `correctPath` and then still pass `enclaveFilePath`? Also, you are clearly writing C++ code, so use the C++ built-in string and memory handling stuff to save yourself all the headaches.

Comment: I had already corrected it and forgotten to correct it in the question. The final JVM crash file is already with the correctPath.